# Is it possible to set a block as a target on a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to send extra arguments to a method on button press, but can't find a way to make addTarget send a selector to do that.

I'd rather use a block anyway, but is there a method for attaching a block to a UIButton at run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by default. You could subclass UIButton to make this happen, though. Someone did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908003/uibutton-block-equivalent-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents-method).

Comment: One of the comments on that answer has a valid reason on why not to subclass, just I case the OP doesn't read past the answer

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can do it easily with BlocksKit library:

```
#import <BlocksKit/UIControl+BlocksKit.h>

[someButton addEventHandler:^(id sender) {
    // some action here
} forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
```

or use RxSwift button.rx.tap observable.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe later for the party, but you can use a simple extension I've made some weeks ago, to accomplish your goal. You can get it [here](https://gist.github.com/valvoline/5b03e80740c26f8eb0be).

And use it as follow:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let aButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 80)
        aButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        aButton.handleControlEvent(.TouchUpInside) { () -> Void in
            NSLog("ich")
        }
        self.view.addSubview(aButton)
    }
}
```