# How to make UIBlockButton suit with ARC?

Tags: ios, uibutton, objective-c-blocks

I am using the `UIBlockButton` code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908003/uibutton-block-equivalent-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents-method):

```
typedef void (^ActionBlock)();

@interface UIBlockButton : UIButton {
  ActionBlock _actionBlock;
}

-(void) handleControlEvent:(UIControlEvents)event 
                 withBlock:(ActionBlock) action;

@implementation UIBlockButton

-(void) handleControlEvent:(UIControlEvents)event 
                 withBlock:(ActionBlock) action
{
  _actionBlock = Block_copy(action);
  [self addTarget:self action:@selector(callActionBlock:) forControlEvents:event];
}

-(void) callActionBlock:(id)sender{
  _actionBlock();
}

-(void) dealloc{
  Block_release(_actionBlock);
  [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

but I changed my code to under ARC, how to change the code to make sure everything works well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header:

```
@interface UIBlockButton : UIButton

- (void) handleControlEvent: (UIControlEvents) event withBlock: (dispatch_block_t) action;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@interface UIBlockButton ()
@property(copy) dispatch_block_t actionBlock;
@end

@implementation UIBlockButton
@synthesize actionBlock;

- (void) handleControlEvent: (UIControlEvents) event withBlock: (dispatch_block_t) action
{
    [self setActionBlock:action];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(callActionBlock:) forControlEvents:event];
}

- (void) callActionBlock: (id) sender
{
    if (actionBlock) actionBlock();
}

@end
```

But note that multiple calls to `handleControlEvent:withBlock:` will overwrite your block, you can’t have different actions for different events with this implementation. Also, you should probably use a different prefix for the class instead of `UI` to prevent potential clashes with Apple’s code.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and replay my question so quickly.

Comment: `[self setActionBlock:action];` can be written as `self.actionBlock = action;`