# how to pass data when button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Lets say I have 10 buttons. For each button i want to pass some text... e.g. Button 1, My New Button 2, etc....

What I want to do is print this text in NSLog.

Hence  I created one method and passed this to button. But I am not getting how can I pass data into it...

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"btnSelected data is %@", sender);
    // I want to print some text for respective button here...    
}
```

But I am not getting... any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
[myButton setAccessibilityValue:@"Some text"];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"btnSelected data is %@", [sender accessibilityValue];);
    // I want to print some text for respective button here...    
}
```

Comment: This is very wrong, conceptually. Cluttering the accessibility options of the UI? No way...

Comment: @JackyBoy And it doesn't even use jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

You can associate data with objects as :

Firstly import this class  : `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Then create a key as

```
static char * kIndexPathAssociationKeySTR = "associated_string_key";
```

then associate string as :
** Here you can associate any type of data with button like : NSMutableArray  or NSString etcetra**

```
NSString *myAttachedValue = @"This is the info I am associating with button";
objc_setAssociatedObject(self.testBtn,
                         kIndexPathAssociationKeySTR,
                         myAttachedValue,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

then access it in your method you called on button event as :

```
- (IBAction)btnTouched:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *valueIs = (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self.testBtn, kIndexPathAssociationKeySTR);
    NSLog(@"value is : %@",valueIs);

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

set tag for the button

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton.tag = 1;
```

now compare tag

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)
    if(button.tag == 1) { //do button 1 stuff
        NSLog(@"btnSelected data is %@", sender);
    }
}
```

Also you can probably checkout Blocks, extend a uibutton to support blocks ([UIButton block equivalent to addTarget:action:forControlEvents: method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908003/uibutton-block-equivalent-to-addtargetactionforcontrolevents-method)).