# Check That The Button Has Received Touch in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wonder if I am doing something wrong in this code:

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:tableView];
    NSLog(@"Current: ", currentTouchPosition);
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"Index Path: ", indexPath);
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}
```

indexPath and currentTouchPosition They are empty

I call method here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *sectionTitle = [artistSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableDictionary *sectionArtists = [artists objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *title = [sectionArtists objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row]];
    NSMutableDictionary *artist = [baseController getCurrentItemByTitle: artistsBD :title];

    NSInteger ID = [artist objectForKey: @"1"];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"listArtists";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"listArtists"];

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"listArtists"];
    cell.lbName.text = [artist objectForKey: @"2"];
    NSInteger *qtdAlbuns = [artistDAO countAlbuns: ID];
    cell.lbDetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i álbuns", qtdAlbuns];
    cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"icones-categorias-artista"];
    cell.imagePricipal.image = [artistDAO getThumb: ID];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage   imageNamed:@"icon-up"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    //cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-up"]];

    [self setImageCornerRadius : cell];

    cell.tag = ID;
    return cell;
}
```

img of button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHuiG.png

when I click the button to currentTouchPosition and indexPath is empty, so I wonder if I'm doing something wrong in the code.

Comment: What are you doing actually? you need every tableview Cell have same button & that button are works same?

Comment: by clicking on the button will expand with the albums of artists, understand? *sorry for my bad english

Comment: I would recommend you to create own class of UITableViewCell. Then in that custom cell class you can create your button. When is particular button in particular cell view tapped you can call a delegate from custom UITableViewCell class to your view controller.

Comment: Solved, I was going the wrong UITableView. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to achieve what you want, is to use UIButton's with blocks, such as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3977305/908621).

Then you won't need your `checkButtonTapped:` method, and instead of `[button addTarget...]` you can simply do this:

```
[button handleControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside
             withBlock:^{
    [self tableView:tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying walking up the view hierarchy from the button:

```
static UITableViewCell *cellAncestorOfView(UIView *view) {
    while (YES) {
        if (view == nil || [view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            return view;
        }
        view = view.superview;
    }
}

- (void)checkButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITableViewCell *cell = cellAncestorOfView(sender);
    if (cell != nil) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        if (indexPath != nil) {
            [self tableView:tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }
}
```